# How to select rows where one field is in multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to query my DB to return all buildings that are a match to an entered postal code. My client has provided me with two tables related to the subject:

```
             buildings
+----+------------+---------------+
| id |    name    | building_code |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  1 | Building A |           001 |
|  2 | Building B |           002 |
|  3 | Building C |           003 |
+----+------------+---------------+

             postal_codes
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+
| id | postal_code | primary | pecondary |
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+
|  1 |   A1A 1A1   |     001 |       002 |
|  2 |   B2B 2B2   |     002 |       003 |
|  3 |   C3C 3C3   |     003 |       001 |
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

Unfortunately for me, the table containing postal codes contains the Building Codes in duplicate (A postal code has a primary building, and a secondary building)

So, when performing a search for buildings with the postal code `A1A`, I need to receive Building A and Building B. This isn't that much of an issue in and of itself, however the only method I've found to do it is incredibly bulky and doesn't leave many options for future proofing.

```
SELECT * FROM buildings
WHERE (building_code IN  (SELECT primary FROM postal_codes
                          WHERE postal_code LIKE '%A1A%')
       OR
       building_code IN  (SELECT secondary FROM postal_codes
                          WHERE postal_code LIKE '%A1A%'))
```

I've tried just doing `building IN (SELECT primary, secondary FROM postal_codes)` but that keeps causing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.* 
FROM   buildings b 
       JOIN postal_codes pc 
         ON b.building_code IN ( pc.primary, pc.secondary ) 
WHERE  postal_code LIKE '%A1A%'
```

**Note :** Used `Distinct` to avoid duplicate records from `Building` table since your original does not duplicate result. If your `postal_codes` table does not have duplicate entries in  `pc.primary` or `pc.secondary` column you can remove the `Distinct`

Or you can use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   buildings B 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   postal_codes PC 
               WHERE  B.building_code IN ( pc.primary, pc.secondary ) 
                      AND PC.postal_code LIKE '%A1A%')
```

Comment: I tried the first code you posted and it didn't work. I got back the entire databse (or at least it seemed like I did, may have been a lot of duplicate rows). However, the second query you posted worked perfectly (and would be extremely simple to update if the client ever wants a tertiary building per postal code).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to join tables like this:

```
select b.* 
  from postal_codes p
  join buildings b
    on b.building_code = p.primary OR b.building_code = p.secondary
 where p.postal_code LIKE '%A1A%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM
(
SELECT primary as b_id FROM postal_codes WHERE postal_code LIKE '%A1A%'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT pecondary as b_id FROM postal_codes WHERE postal_code LIKE '%A1A%'
) x
inner join buildings as b on x.b_id = b.building_code
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.